# Create custom Modifier element in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

According to Compose's Documentation, We can add custom Modifier classes like the following:

```kotlin
class SpacingModifier(val space: Dp) : Modifier.Element
fun Modifier.innerSpacing(space: Dp) = this.then(SpacingModifier(space))

@Composable
fun MyListOfItems(
  list: List<Model>,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
  LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
    items(list) { model ->
      ViewHolder(model)
      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(/*I need the innerSpacing value here*/))
    }
  }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewList() {
  MyListOfItems(
    list = listOf(
      Model(text = "Hello 1", checked = true),
      Model(text = "Hello 2", checked = false),
      Model(text = "Hello 3", checked = true),
      Model(text = "Hello 4", checked = true),
      Model(text = "Hello 5", checked = false)
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
      .background(Color.Red)
      .innerSpacing(16.dp) // <- My extension function here
  )
}
```

If I have the ability to declare extension functions for the Modifier, how do I access it inside a composable in the example above?

Comment: I have an article here that shows how to create custom modifiers: https://fvilarino.medium.com/creating-a-custom-modifier-attribute-on-jetpack-compose-f100c6bcb987

Comment: Why not just pass `innerSpace` as a parameter to `MyListOfItems`?

Comment: Because in reality, there are like 5-10 parameters related to the configuration of my composable and I wish that they are chained with the modifier property. Even as general curiosity, google provides such a code snippet as the first thing on [Modifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier). How do we retrieve the properties?

Comment: Look at `any`, `all`, `foldIn` and `foldOut` which allow you to extract information from a `Modifier`.

Answer (score 1):

`Modifier` is an ordered, immutable collection of modifier elements that decorate or add behavior to Compose UI elements. For example, backgrounds, padding and click event listeners decorate or add behavior to rows, text or buttons.

Modifiers are not to be interpreted directly by your Composable functions but `Layout` which is root for most composable functions such as `Row`, `Column`, `Box`, or `SubcomposeLayout` which is parent for `LazyColumn`, `LazyRow`, or `BoxWithConstraints`.

```
@Composable inline fun Layout(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    measurePolicy: MeasurePolicy
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
    val viewConfiguration = LocalViewConfiguration.current
    ReusableComposeNode<ComposeUiNode, Applier<Any>>(
        factory = ComposeUiNode.Constructor,
        update = {
            set(measurePolicy, ComposeUiNode.SetMeasurePolicy)
            set(density, ComposeUiNode.SetDensity)
            set(layoutDirection, ComposeUiNode.SetLayoutDirection)
            set(viewConfiguration, ComposeUiNode.SetViewConfiguration)
        },
        skippableUpdate = materializerOf(modifier),
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun SubcomposeLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    measurePolicy: SubcomposeMeasureScope.(Constraints) -> MeasureResult
) {
    SubcomposeLayout(
        state = remember { SubcomposeLayoutState() },
        modifier = modifier,
        measurePolicy = measurePolicy
    )
}
```

You can chain your Modifiers such as

```
private fun Modifier.getBadgeModifier(
    badgeState: BadgeState,
    shape: Shape
) = this
    .materialShadow(badgeState = badgeState)
    .then(
        badgeState.borderStroke?.let { borderStroke ->
            this.border(borderStroke, shape = shape)
        } ?: this
    )
    .background(
        badgeState.backgroundColor,
        shape = shape
    )
```

Modifier.materialShadow is also a Modifier that is chained to draw shadow based on a class called badgeState which wraps shapes, shadow and more.

```
class BadgeState(
    var maxNumber: Int = 99,
    var circleShapeThreshold: Int = 1,
    @IntRange(from = 0, to = 99) var roundedRadiusPercent: Int = 50,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    var horizontalPadding: Dp = 4.dp,
    var verticalPadding: Dp = 0.dp,
    textColor: Color,
    var fontSize: TextUnit,
    var fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    var fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    var fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    var textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    var shadow: MaterialShadow? = null,
    var borderStroke: BorderStroke? = null,
    showBadgeThreshold: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE,
)
```

Also when you need to add  multiple params to a Composable function or access these parameters you can do it as `Text` Composable uses `TextStyle`

```
   @Composable
    fun Text(
        text: String,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        // Other properties
        style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
    ) 

    class TextStyle(
        val color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        val fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
        val fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
        val fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
        val fontSynthesis: FontSynthesis? = null,
        val fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
        val fontFeatureSettings: String? = null,
        val letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
        val baselineShift: BaselineShift? = null,
        val textGeometricTransform: TextGeometricTransform? = null,
        val localeList: LocaleList? = null,
        val background: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        val textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
        val shadow: Shadow? = null,
        val textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
        val textDirection: TextDirection? = null,
        val lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
        val textIndent: TextIndent? = null
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need innerspacing of child items in a `LazyColumn` or a `LazyRow`, you should use `verticalArrangement = modifier.spacedBy(..)` or `horizontalArrangement = modifier.spacedBy(...)`